# how to run multiple sites with dedicated ip on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, server

how i can set up nginx on aws instance ec2 for run 2 sites each with personal ip?

i created t2.mini instance and give second private ip then i added 2 elastic ips and bind with instance

then i use command for add ip to network
`sudo ip addr add 123.123.123.1/20 dev eth0`
(here i don’t understand, i need to add a public or private ip, and i added all)

**site1.com.conf**

```
server {
    server_name site1.com www.site1.com;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/site1.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
    listen 123.123.123.1:80;
}
```

where listen public ip for domain site1.com

**nginx.conf** i keep default

in route 53 i created two zones for each domains, add A record with value public ip of my instance

and then two sites cannot be reached

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add any further IP addresses manually to the server, these will be managed by AWS for you including binding to the server and establishing and managing the mappings tables for public to private IP address.

Regarding the resolution, instances on AWS do not have exposure to the public IP address, this is translated in the internet gateway layer to match against the instances corresponding private IP address.

This means that because you may have configured to listen on a public IP address, that IP address will never be bound to your server.

Instead add your listen to be **the private IP address** of the instance that matches the public IP address in the ENI.

Once it is listening on the private IP addresses the hostnames in your Route 53 should be connectable via resolution to the public IP addresses.

Your instance will have access to any IP address that has been added to the ENI.

AWS have published more information on working with multiple IP addresses in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/MultipleIP.html) document.

Answer (score 0):

As you added a second private IP on instance, your OS will have only one interface, with its primary IP (private). You don't need to add the second IP (private) in your OS level.
In this setup it means that your nginx will listen in only one interface and you can configure two different web sites with its particular host name.
It doesn't mean your both web sites will have the same IP, in fact each one will have its own IP, as you created two Elatic IPs and two Route53 zones. But both will point to the  some internal IP.

Now if you really need to configure nginx to listen on two different IP, you can add another interface on your instance.
In this setup your OS will have two interfaces, each one with its own primary IP (private).
Everything related to Route53 is the same as explained above, but instead of point to the same private IP each public one will point to its own pair of private one.

So you don't need to add anything on SO, neither private or public. AWS does all the "magic" for you.